# App Store not listing down In App purchase after approval from Apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, auto-renewable

My app's new version with subscription feature went live around 10 hr before but "in-app purchase" is not working , where as I tested my development build with adhoc profile they seems to work properly.

What should I do ?

Comment: Don't use your iTune connect Apple id Email address for purchase for Subscription. Use different Apple id for live Subscription.

Comment: @Wos I am not using that email address. Problem is SKProduct request is not getting SKProduct from apple, but same time development build is getting all required data from apple.

Comment: It can take up to 48hrs for everything to work as expected. Is the in-app-purchase also approved? You need to send it separately into review.

Comment: It took 15 hr to be updated.